# describeSObject for Individual object

Tags: describesobject, individual

Is it possible to call the describeSObject method for the Individual object?
I am using the Partner-Connection-API

```
com.sforce.soap.partner.DescribeSObjectResult describeSObject(java.lang.String sObjectType)
```

The Individual object is activated on the Org and I am using API version 42

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the API documentation for [Individual](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_individual.htm), yes it is. You will need API v42.0 or later and "Data Protection and Privacy" needs to be enabled.

Users with a Customer Community, Partner Community, or Customer Portal licence won't be able to access it.

---

Extract from a `describeGlobal` call against v42.0.

```
<sobjects>
    <activateable>false</activateable>
    <createable>true</createable>
    <custom>false</custom>
    <customSetting>false</customSetting>
    <deletable>true</deletable>
    <deprecatedAndHidden>false</deprecatedAndHidden>
    <feedEnabled>false</feedEnabled>
    <hasSubtypes>false</hasSubtypes>
    <idEnabled>true</idEnabled>
    <isSubtype>false</isSubtype>
    <keyPrefix>0PK</keyPrefix>
    <label>Individual</label>
    <labelPlural>Individuals</labelPlural>
    <layoutable>true</layoutable>
    <mergeable>false</mergeable>
    <mruEnabled>true</mruEnabled>
    <name>Individual</name>
    <queryable>true</queryable>
    <replicateable>true</replicateable>
    <retrieveable>true</retrieveable>
    <searchable>true</searchable>
    <triggerable>true</triggerable>
    <undeletable>false</undeletable>
    <updateable>true</updateable>
</sobjects>
```

---

Direct SOAP call to `describeSObject`:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <urn:SessionHeader><urn:sessionId>00D700000000001!AQoAQKmw.Not.A.Real.Session.Id.8mnITkhsVehux5kxLJnZMRzdi</urn:sessionId>
      </urn:SessionHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:describeSObject>
         <urn:sObjectType>Individual</urn:sObjectType>
      </urn:describeSObject>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Partial response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <LimitInfoHeader>
         <!-- ... -->
      </LimitInfoHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <describeSObjectResponse>
         <result>
            <activateable>false</activateable>
            <childRelationships>
            <!-- ... -->
            <compactLayoutable>true</compactLayoutable>
            <createable>true</createable>
            <custom>false</custom>
            <customSetting>false</customSetting>
            <deletable>true</deletable>
            <deprecatedAndHidden>false</deprecatedAndHidden>
            <feedEnabled>false</feedEnabled>
            <!-- ... -->
            <hasSubtypes>false</hasSubtypes>
            <idEnabled>true</idEnabled>
            <isSubtype>false</isSubtype>
            <keyPrefix>0PK</keyPrefix>
            <label>Individual</label>
            <labelPlural>Individuals</labelPlural>
            <layoutable>true</layoutable>
            <mergeable>false</mergeable>
            <mruEnabled>true</mruEnabled>
            <name>Individual</name>
            <networkScopeFieldName xsi:nil="true"/>
            <queryable>true</queryable>
            <replicateable>true</replicateable>
            <retrieveable>true</retrieveable>
            <searchLayoutable>true</searchLayoutable>
            <searchable>true</searchable>
            <supportedScopes>
               <label>All individuals</label>
               <name>everything</name>
            </supportedScopes>
            <supportedScopes>
               <label>My individuals</label>
               <name>mine</name>
            </supportedScopes>
            <supportedScopes>
               <label>My team's individuals</label>
               <name>team</name>
            </supportedScopes>
            <triggerable>true</triggerable>
            <undeletable>false</undeletable>
            <updateable>true</updateable>
            <urlDetail>https://xzy-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/{ID}</urlDetail>
            <urlEdit>https://xzy--dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/{ID}/e</urlEdit>
            <urlNew>https://xzy--dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/0PK/e</urlNew>
         </result>
      </describeSObjectResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```